# Will constraints set up in code override constraints created using AutoLayout and SizeClasses?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I set up a constraint this way:

```
constraintButtonUpgrade = NSLayoutConstraint (item: buttonUpgrade,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 500)
        self.view.addConstraint(constraintButtonUpgrade)
```

Will this code modify the constant of the same constraint (with the same `item`, `attribute`, `toItem` that I created in the Storyboard view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this adds a new constraint which possibly fights with the other already existing constraint leading to ambiguous layout (ie auto layout will break one of them randomly to resolve the layout). You need to remove the other constraint first to have it work cleanly, alternatively, you can also just modify the other constraint instead of creating a new one.